# How to install all i386 libs to match installed 64 libs for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit

Looking for turnkey solution for 12.04 lts. 
That is the equivalent of doing an `apt-get install ia32-libs` from earlier Ubuntu distros

Reason: games that need 32 bit support or anything really. Just want to install all 32 bit equivs of installed 64 bit libs with out having to do it one at a time trial and error style.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

In particular, run the following in sequence:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you still have un-upgraded packages, run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f` as many times as needed till all packages are upgraded. If you still have un-upgraded pacakages try continuing and see if it works. Reboot. Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

To check this has been done, run `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, and look for the output `i386`. Then cycle through `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f` again.

Let us know if this works, and if you can successfully get your desired apps working.

**NOTE**

Make sure you have selected the "Main Server" for downloading software and updates in the "Software and Updates" settings. I've included the screenshot below so you can see what it looks like. I'm not on Ubuntu right now so I'm not sure how to get there, but it shouldn't be so hard to find.

[image]